# how to determine the child of a <ul> using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to determine the child of a UL using jquery?

im trying to change the class of the LI items in a UL based on their child type in a clickevent of an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see following example

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the child elements then you can use

```
$("yourulid > li").addClass("something");
```

and if you want to get the descendant elements then

```
$("yourulid li").addClass("something");
```

See it working **[here](http://jsbin.com/ecuno)**.